# 2-connected graphs and paths

Tags: graph-theory, solution-verification

I want to prove that if a graph is 2-connected, for any three vertices $u,v,w$ there exists a path from $u$ to $w$ containing $v$. Is the following argument correct?

By a known theorem, there exist two internally disjoint paths from $u$ to $v$, call them $P(u,v)$, $Q(u,v)$ and two from $v$ to $w$, call them $S(v,w)$, $T(v,w)$, from which we pick one, say $S(v,w)$. If $S(v,w)$ doesn't intersect both $P(u,v)$, $Q(u,v)$ internally, it's easy to construct a path from $u$ to $w$ passing through $v$. So let's assume $S(v,w)$ intersects both $P(u,v)$ and $Q(u,v)$ internally. Let $c$ be the last intersection of $S(v,w)$ with $P(u,v)$ or $Q(u,v)$ and assume wlog that it belongs to $P(u,v)$. Then $Q(u,v)$ joined with $P(u,v)$ run backwards from $v$ to $c$ joined with $S(c,w)$ is a path from $u$ to $w$ containing $v$.

I'd like you to also let me know if there's a clearly shorter and clearer argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your argument is essentially correct, but there are a few ways to make it better.

"By a known theorem" -> This is Menger's Theorem. There are many version of it, so you are usually safe to just say "Menger's Theorem" when you want to use anything in that vein.

"$T(v,w)$" -> You never use this. Just say there exists $S(v,w)$.

"If $S(v,w)$ doesn't intersect both $P(u,v)$, $Q(u,v)$" -> "Both" should be "either".

"let's assume $S(v,w)$ intersects both $P(u,v)$ and $Q(u,v)$ internally" -> We can combine this with the previous case if we get rid of the word "internally." Specifically, $S$ intersects both $P$ and $Q$ at $v$. Take the last time on $S$ it intersects, and run your argument from there.

Personally, I find the argument simpler if you switch $P$ and $Q$ with $S$ and $T$. That is, there are two internally disjoint $v$ to $w$ paths $S$ and $T$, and a $u$ to $v$ path $P$. Let $x$ be the first vertex of $P$ (going from $u$ to $v$) which is on $S \cup T$. Without loss of generality, suppose $x$ in on $S$. Then following $P$ from $u$ to $x$, $S$ from $x$ to $v$, and then $T$ from $v$ to $w$ is a $u$ to $v$ to $w$ path.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughtful reply. I wrote "If $S(v,w)$ doesn't intersect both $P(u,v)$..." in order to include the cases where S intersects only one of them. The case I discuss refers only to S intersecting both P and Q. Is this still wrong/unclear?

Comment: It's an English language issue. There are four cases: A and B, A and not B, not A and B, not A and not B. You explain the case A and B, so to condense the other three cases into one case, you should write not(A and B), which is to say either not A or not B. Essentially, using the word "both" with a negative can be ambiguous: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/151864/is-it-right-to-use-both-in-negative-sentences

Comment: Oh of course, thank you. Do you think the other cases would merit an explicit discussion?

Comment: Depends on your audience. At any rate you can write it with no cases (as I've done in the answer).

Answer (score 2):

Adding to Bob Krueger's answer, because you ask for a shorter and clearer argument, here is an alternative proof.

Add a new vertex $z$ with two edges $uz$ and $zw$, this defines a graph $G'$. It is easy to see that $G'$ is 2-connected (by proving that there is no cutpoint, or by using an ear-decomposition). Then by Menger's theorem, $G'$ has two node-disjoint paths $P_1$, $P_2$ from $z$ to $v$. Remove the two edges $uz$ and $zw$ from $P_1$ and $P_2$, and we get a path from $u$ to $v$ and a path from $w$ to $v$, that are node-disjoint.

Comment: This is very clever!

Comment: I’ve just realized that this problem is a special case of the fan lemma, and your proof is what the typical proof is.

Comment: Thanks, nice proof.